# OneLogin: get suspended users for specific time

Tags: api, query-string, onelogin

looking for your help as the OneLogin support won´t help as it is out of their scope.

I am trying to get all suspended users (at best for a specific date) via python script for an API:
For sure `https://api.us.onelogin.com/api/1/users` will list all users (even if limited to 50 results) - but wanna get users only for one day (or within last 24hours anyway.

however I can´t filter by "*status*" or "*updated_at*":
E.g. `https://api.us.onelogin.com/api/1/users?updated_at=2021-06-10T23:59:59` will return `"updated_at cannot be used to query on User"`

If I run  `https://api.us.onelogin.com/api/1/users?since=2021-06-10T23:59:59`
I will get only an err msg as "*since*"  will only  ".. return results that meet criteria based on created_at attribute values...."

The only way I figured seems a bit complicated:

1. List all users via *Event 551* (user suspended by ...) but here I get only the *user_id*  => `https://api.us.onelogin.com/api/1/events?event_type_id=551&since=2021-06-10T00:00:01Z&fields=user_id`
2. and run an additional function which is need to query again to get all users details => `https://api.us.onelogin.com/api/1/users/<user_id>`

is there a better or easy way I oversee ? this would be very helpful to make my script way more dynamic

cheers
Felix

Answer (score 0):

The [List Users v2 API](https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/2/users/list-users) supports the query parameters you are looking for.

Here is an example request for listing users updated between two timestamps with the status of `2` (user suspended):

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://YOUR_DOMAIN.onelogin.com/api/2/users?updated_since=2021-06-16T00:00:00Z&updated_until=2021-06-17T00:00:00Z&status=2' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_TOKEN'
```